# How to deploy code from bit bucket to heroku?

Tags: heroku, bitbucket

while am doing auto deploying code from bit bucket to heroku, I got some configuration issue in bitbucket-pipelines.yml.

```
 HEROKU_API_KEY: 'XXXXXX'
 HEROKU_APP_NAME: 'XXXX'
 ZIP_FILE: 'your-app-sources.tar.gz'
 WAIT: 'true'
```

Above is the configuration for Heroku.

But while deploying it gives me an error near "ZIP_FILE":'..'

like that mentioned file/folder not found.

My question is which value i have to place for "ZIP_FILE":'XXXX'.

Please help me to go forward.

Note: am doing auto deployment from bitbucket to heroku for any push done on 
  master branch.
  Thanks,SrinivasaRao.CH

Answer (score 1):

You first need to create a step to build your code's image and generate that zip file there. Then create a step to deploy your code using the variables you are mentioning. So in your bitbucket-pipelines.yml file paste this:

```
image: node:10.15.0
    clone:
        depth: full
    
    pipelines:
        default:
        - step:
            name: Build
            caches:
                - node
            script:
                - npm install
                - git archive --format=tar.gz master -o your-app-sources.tar.gz
            artifacts: 
                - your-app-sources.tar.gz
        - step:
            name: Deploy
            deployment: production            
            script:
                - pipe: atlassian/heroku-deploy:1.2.1
            variables:
                HEROKU_API_KEY: $HEROKU_API_KEY
                HEROKU_APP_NAME: $HEROKU_APP_NAME
                ZIP_FILE: your-app-sources.tar.gz
```

Now every time you do a git push your code will auto-deploy on heroku. You do not need to use the WAIT part. Also 'your-app-sources' is a placeholder name. Just name it whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a previous step in the deploy process.

```
- step:
   name: Create ZIP_FILE
   script:
     - tar czfv my_app.tgz /path/to/src
   artifacts:
     - my_app.tgz
```

Such that, you can access the tar.gz app in your next step (the one you have above).

Everything should look like this:

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Create ZIP_FILE
        script:
          - tar czfv my_app.tgz /path/to/src
        artifacts:
          - my_app.tgz
    - step:
        name: Deploy to Heroku
        deployment: test   # set to test, staging or production
        script:
          - pipe: atlassian/heroku-deploy:1.1.1
            variables:
              HEROKU_API_KEY: $HEROKU_API_KEY
              HEROKU_APP_NAME: $HEROKU_APP_NAME
              ZIP_FILE: "my_app.tgz"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your local project, generate a new tgz file of your project:

```
npm pack
```

Once done, copy the new `.tgz` generated name and paste it as the value of the "ZIP_FILE" attribute, and push it to your repo. This works for me!